# Python selenium get page title

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, page-title

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://hapondo.qa/rent/doha/apartments/studio")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/head/title"))
)

print(element.text)
```

Unable to get page title under headless option? Tried to wait and even tried `driver.title`

Comment: what is the error you are getting? You are using incorrect locator - css_selector or xpath ?

Comment: @Sureshmani sorry, just corrected it now. but still not solved the issue.

Comment: Where is your WebDriverWait line? because it works okay for me if I have it before print(driver.title)

Comment: @MatthewKing i tried multiple times but getting empty print. https://repl.it/@AmericanY/issue#main.py

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to take care of a couple of things as follows:

- To retrieve the *Page Title* instead of using a [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) you need to use `driver.title`
- The [hapondo](https://hapondo.qa/rent/doha/apartments/studio) website contains [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled elements.

---

### Solution

To extract the *Page Title* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `title_contains()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://hapondo.qa/rent/doha/apartments/studio')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("hapondo"))
  print(driver.title)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Studio Apartments for rent in Doha | hapondo
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to make selenium wait before getting contents from the actual website which loads after the landing page through IEDriverServer and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53438182/how-to-make-selenium-wait-before-getting-contents-from-the-actual-website-which/53442105#53442105)

Comment: how about if the page title like [this](https://hapondo.qa/rent/al-daayen/lusail/les-maisons-blanches/3-bedroom-furnished-apartment-2266) how can i add more strings?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη The phrase `hapondo` is a string which I'm sure would be present in the _Page Title_ for any webpage with `https://hapondo.qa`. You can use any string which suits your requirement.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I had a look at the **Rent** section but was unable to conclude which string among `bedroom`, `furnished`, `apartment`, `in` or  `by` could be common within the _Page Title_ for all the rented properties. You can use the common term as the expected _text_ within the Expected Conditions.

Answer (score -2):

By "page title", I'm assuming you mean the text that appears on the tab at the top of the browser.

Solution that changes little of your code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"[path]")
driver.get("https://hapondo.qa/rent/doha/apartments/studio")


element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/head/title"))
    )

print(element.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
Output: Studio Apartments for rent in Doha | hapondo
```

Another way of getting that text is by simply using `driver.title`.

"The `title` method is used to retrieve the title of the webpage the user is currently working on. "

Source: [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-title-of-a-webpage-using-selenium-in-python/)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"[PATH]")
driver.get("https://hapondo.qa/rent/doha/apartments/studio")
time.sleep(2)

print(driver.title)
#Output: Studio Apartments for rent in Doha | hapondo
```

Alternate solution which changes very little:

Comment: That's still not answering the question. i need that to done on the website which i provided. i tried `driver.title` and got nothing printed out

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη You should update your code to show the headless option is set as that is related to cause of the problem

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, Nope, worked for me: `Studio Apartments for rent in Doha | hapondo` was outputted

Comment: @MatthewKing you are correct. the headless option is the cause of the issue. still trying to figure out a way for it.

Comment: @lionrocker221 sorry, i noticed that the issue is regarding headless browser. do you have any clue ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη try the first code block in the solution, it does everything you have been doing except accesses the "innerHTML" attribute instead of the text.

Comment: @lionrocker221 i tried it under headless browser and still unable to get the output. but without headless it's works fine. here's the code https://bpa.st/SOSA