# Wait for some time before getting the website source code

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape a website to get the heading and summary of the news. The problem I am facing is that when we first open the website, a redirect appears and we have to wait 8 seconds for the website to load. The problem I am facing is that the web data that is beign stored is that of the redirect instead of the main website.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Specify the path to the ChromeDriver executable
chrome_driver_path = "C:/webdrivers/chromedriver"

# Initialize the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

# Navigate to website
driver.get("https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/markets/stocks/news")
time.sleep(10)
data2, data4 = [], []

while True:
    # Extract data
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "example-class"})
    for item in data:
        data2.append(item.find_all('h3'))
        data4.append(item.find_all('p'))

    try:
        # Find the "Load More" button
        load_more_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.autoload_continue")
        # Click the button
        load_more_button.click()
    except:
        break

# Close the browser
driver.quit()

print(data2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for switch to your final url:

```
wait.until(EC.url_to_be('https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/markets/stocks/news'))
```

##### Example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

url = 'https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/markets/stocks/news'
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.url_to_be('https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/markets/stocks/news'))
```

Answer (score 1):

An ideal approach would be to wait for the **News** heading within the [webpage](https://m.economictimes.com/markets/stocks/news) to be visibible.

---

### Solution

To wait for the **News** heading to be visibible you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/markets/stocks/news')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.h1")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/markets/stocks/news')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h1[@class='h1' and text()='News']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Alternative

You can also wait for the **Page Title** of the [webpage](https://m.economictimes.com/markets/stocks/news) to contain *`Stocks in News Today`* as follows:

```
driver.get('https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/markets/stocks/news')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("Stocks in News Today"))
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Python selenium get page title](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64794657/7429447)
- [How to make selenium wait before getting contents from the actual website which loads after the landing page through IEDriverServer and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099102/7429447)