# Python driver.get_page_source after clicking the button

Tags: python, selenium, driver

the Python script gets the page and clicks the button that cause reloading the main page content.
Then I try to get the page source of the reloaded page, but still having the content of the first one. Probably it should be refreshed somehow.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(base_listing_url)
time.sleep(10)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.fTomoL').click()
time.sleep(10)
print(driver.page_source) #This returns the first page's content
```

Comment: Can you share the url?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) of the new page to [render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233385/request-fully-javascript-rendered-html-source-from-a-website-and-find-all-iframe/47237075#47237075) within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) and you can adapt any of the following approaches:

You can wait for the *Page Title* to change:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.fTomoL').click()
# wait till the page title contains the word Facebook
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("Facebook"))
print(driver.page_source)
```

You can wait for a *visible element* to be *visible*:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.fTomoL').click()
# wait till the page title contains the word Facebook
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='Some Heading']")))
print(driver.page_source)
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to make selenium wait before getting contents from the actual website which loads after the landing page through IEDriverServer and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53438182/how-to-make-selenium-wait-before-getting-contents-from-the-actual-website-which/53442105#53442105)
- [Python + Selenium: Wait until element is fully loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905)